# Whats is Container class in C++, Can any one give good example?

Tags: c++

I want to know :

DEFINITION,USE & EXAMPLE OF CONTAINER CLASS IN C++....

If you know please reply it...

Comment: Never heard of any such thing.

Comment: Examples include std::list and std::map -- see [stl containers](https://www.google.com/search?q=stl+containers).

Answer (score 2):

"Container" is a generic term (a "concept") used in the standard to refer to containers in the standard library: `vector`, `deque`, `forward_list` (C++11), `list`, `array` (C++11), `map`, `set`, `unordered_map` (C++11), `unordered_set` (C++11).

Searching for these should give you plenty of documentation and examples.

**EDIT**

You can start e.g. on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a `container` class does not exist. It is a term used to name one of the *container* classes (classes that contains objects): `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::deque`, `std::set` ...